# Dividing my website into three columns of unequal length

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have been trying to divide my website into three columns, two of 15% and one of 70% which would be the middle one and would contain the content of the website. But I wasnt able to make the three columns take 100% of the website.
I am using the following code:

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="column1"> <h1> this is column 1</h1>tting, remairem</div>
    <div class="column2"><h1> this is column 2</h1>Lorem Ip Lorem</div>
    <div class="column1"><h1> this is column 1</h1>Lorem Ipsum ing Lorem</div>
</div>
```

And styled it with this CSS

```css
div.content{
    width:100%;
}
div.column1{
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    background-color:aqua;

}
div.column2{
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

After running it I get the following result.

[image]

As you can see the three columns are not taking 100% width of the website, I have checked and I don't have any padding or margin that would avoid the columns to take 100% of the space.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I would like to add that if I only add one column the max space it takes is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r0NS.png)

Might then this be a problem of the nav bar?

Comment: Look into flex or grid. Floats are not the right tool for this anymore

Comment: you also have the same problem with your navbar

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the whole html code.

Comment: `width:100%` would be width of parent. Where is this div.content placed?

Comment: @SurajRao the div.content is placed just below the navbar inside the body tag.

Comment: As othrs mentioned, its difficult to say without seeing the rest of the html

Comment: Is there a way in which I could attach the whole code, without copy paste?

Comment: We need to see your HTML structure, but it doesn’t need heaps of content. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Although grid or flex would be more suitable that’s not explaining the width problem.